# htaccess regular expression syntax

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want redirect url

```
http://www.domain.com/category/abc-xyz-zzz-2010-150857.html
to 
http://www.domain.com/category/150857-abc-xyz-zzz-2010.html
```

But if

```
http://www.domain.com/category/150857-abc-xyz-zzz-2010.html
not redirect
```

this is my htaccess but not work

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([A-Za-z]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1/$3-$2.html [L,R=301]
```

Pleas help me fix it

I fixed

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([A-Za-z]*)-([^.]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1/$4-$2-$3.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/([0-9]+)-([A-Za-z0-9]+).html$ $1/$3-$2.html [L,R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)-([a-zA-Z]*)-(\d+)-(\d+).html$ category/$5-$1-$2-$3-$4.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^.]+)/([A-Za-z]+)-([0-9]+).html$ $1/$3-$2.html
```

Your problem here is that you don't take the dashes or even the second group of numbers into account. This one should work:

```
^(.+)/([A-Za-z\-]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)\.html$ $1/$4-$2-$3.html
```